# Request method 'DELETE' not supported in Spring

Tags: angularjs, spring

i'm trying to access a rest method via a angular service. here's my code for the rest method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController { 

  @RequestMapping(value ="/removeUserRole/{roleId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void removeUserRole(@PathVariable("roleId")Long roleId){
        System.out.println("inside delete method");
    }

}
```

and here is my angularJs service method.

```
App.factory('manageRoleService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return {
            getUserRoleDetails: $resource('api/getUserRoleDetails', {}, {
                query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
            }),
            removeUserRole: $resource('api/removeUserRole/:roleId', {}, {
                delete: {method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@roleId'}}
            })
        };
    }]);
```

The get method works fine. but when i try to invoke delete method it gives the following error.

405 Method Not Allowed

Request method 'DELETE' not supported

What am i doing wrong here. i tried following some threads on this same issue but nothing helped out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show, please, as StackTrace from the server on the matter. And it would be great, if you switched on INFO logging level for MVC and showed logs here too.

Comment: This is whats printed in the server log   15:20:01,603 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-27) Request method 'DELETE' not supported

Comment: You might want to put log level for org.springframework.web.servlet to debug or even trace and see if you have any weird mappings printed there.

Answer (score 1):

In your `DELETE` url template you're using `:roleId` placeholder but later provide `id` variable name.

Since the part after the last `/` is empty Spring cannot find the correct mapping.

Change

```
 {id: '@roleId'}
```

to:

```
 {roleId: '@roleId'}
```

Assuming that `@roleId` refers to the property of the data object you have - maybe it should be just `@id`?

Comment: hi i tried changing it as u mentioned but getting the same error. Then i went on and changed it parameter name to id.but still getting the same error.                                                                  removeUserRole: $resource('api/removeUserRole/:id', {}, {
                delete: {method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'}}
            })

Comment: @ChathruakaWaas Where is your GET handler? In the same class? Please post it. Also please look into your browser console and check what url is the DELETE request sent to. Another option might be testing it with curl.

Answer (score 1):

i got it solved by playing around a bit. i guess it was a mismatch between the url patterns.

here's my new code.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/role")
public class RoleController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RoleController.class);

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<ModulePermission> getAllRoles(){
        return roleService.getModulePermissions();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}",method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") Long id){
       logger.info("Deleting the role with id:" + id);
       roleService.deleteRole(id);
    }
}

App.factory('manageRoleService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return {
            getUserRoleDetails: $resource('api/role', {}, {
                query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
            }),
            removeUserRole: $resource('api/role/:id', {}, {
                delete: {method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'}}
            })
        };
    }]);
```

but now when i debug the rest method it seems the value is not getting passed. Its printed as null.

Comment: Got it fixed by using pathVariable instead of pathParam. Thanks for all the advice's.